# How to kill the two background processes in RestRserve?

Tags: r, rest, process

When I run a R scrip which libray RestRserve for web service, I notice that RestRserve will build two process in the background:
[image]

However, when I shut down the session, I found there is still one process running in the background:
[image]

So I have to kill it manually every time or it keeps running. I want to know is there any method to manage the RestRserve two processes efficiently?

Comment: Since it's a flaw with the package, you probably should file an issue on the [author's github](https://github.com/cran/RestRserve/issues)